# log $(this).val() in Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I found a fiddle that logs when an input field changes value.
However i would like to log the new value as well. I have tried all the combinations i found online, but cant get it to work. here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/XezmB/8/

index

```
<input type="number" id="n" value="5" step=".5"/>
```

script

```
    $(":input").bind('keyup change click', function (e) {
    if (! $(this).data("previousValue") || 
           $(this).data("previousValue") != $(this).val()
       )
   {
        console.log("changed");           
        $(this).data("previousValue", $(this).val());
   }
        
});


$(":input").each(function () {
    $(this).data("previousValue", $(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that by changing the 6th line of your shared code.

From:

```
console.log("changed");
```

To:

```
console.log("changed: ", $(this).val() );
```